# Loading contents of a webpage into database

Tags: html, database

I've got several pages about products that I want to load into a database and instead of creating a separate html page for each product, I was thinking of creating a single page that will display whatever product the user clicks on. Each product page will have a similar structure with its name, picture, description, bullet points for features (varies from product to product), price.

My question is if I want to store all those information in a database (I imagine I would need a different field for each paragraph, picture, name, each bullet point, etc) is there a way to get around that? To store all those information in a single field or as few as possible and still keep the formatting. It seems like I would be overloaded with the number of fields I have to manage.

I'm starting to doubt if this was even a good idea to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not store all that information in a single field.  If you are going to do that, then just create the HTML page and save yourself the trouble of having a database that you aren't properly utilizing.

What you need to do is identify the relationship between all parts of your page.  For example, if a single product can have multiple photos you would want to define a multi table relationship that defines a one-to-many relationship between the `Product` and `ProductImage` tables.

Grasping how relational databases relate to the data you are working with can be difficult at first and it might pay off to hire someone for a few hours to go over what you are trying to do and how to implement this effectively using a DB.  Since it is a real world example for you it will be an excellent way to learn.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first person to want to do something like this. It's a very common problem that has a well established solution. You need to use what's called a [web content management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_content_management_system). WCMSs allow you to use a common template throughout your website while filling in specific stuff for each page. I recommend [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) because it's easy to setup, easy to use, and most web hosts support it. But you can also look at stuff like [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) or [Drupal](http://drupal.org/). Wordpress is more blog centric though and Drupal has a steep learning curve.